# Using VLookUp for a partial search

Tags: excel

I have two tables in excel.

In table 1, one column contains a list of order numbers. This is done the format of `XXXX-YYYY` where `X` is an integer and `Y` is a letter. For example `3485-XTIP`

Table 2 also has an order number column but this time it's in the format `XXXX-YYYY (ZZ)` where `Z` is the initials of the customer who made the order. Example: `3485-XTIP (KN)`

How can I use a VLookUp to search for the order number in Table 2 but only using the `XXXX-YYYY` part? I tried using `TRUE` for an approximate search but it still failed for some reason.

This is what I have

```
=VLOOKUP("I3",'Table2 '!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

I am open to any alternatives other than VLookup for this situation.

Note that there are hundreds of order numbers and entering the strings manually will take forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*` as wildcard and add it at the end of the order number so that your VLOOKUP will match any order plus any other characters that come after it:

```
=VLOOKUP(I3&"*", 'Table2 '!A:B, 2, 0)
```

`*` will match anything after the order number.

---

Note: `0` and `False` have the same behaviour here.

Comment: @Theman Awesome! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tickmark outline and at the same time, mark your Q as solved :)